# How to count and getting the sum of value for unique Ids in a Spark Dataframe?

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe

I have the following Dataframe and i am looking to aggregate by ids and also sum the 'value' column for each unique id:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import spark.implicits._

// some data...
val df = Seq(
  (1, 2),
  (1, 4),
  (1, 1),
  (2, 2),
  (2, 2),
  (3, 2),
  (3, 1),
  (3, 1)
).toDF("id","value")

df.show()
```

gives the following:

```
+---+-----+
| id|value|
+---+-----+
|  1|    2|
|  1|    4|
|  1|    1|
|  2|    2|
|  2|    2|
|  3|    2|
|  3|    1|
|  3|    1|
+---+-----+
```

Using the count function I know I can count the unique ids:

```
df.select("id").groupBy($"id").count.orderBy($"id".asc).show()

+---+-----+
| id|count|
+---+-----+
|  1|    3|
|  2|    2|
|  3|    3|
+---+-----+
```

but I also want to sum (or get the average of) the values for each of the unique ids. So the resulting table should be as follows:

```
+---+-----+----------+
| id|count|valueCount|
+---+-----+----------+
|  1|    3|         7|
|  2|    2|         4|
|  3|    3|         4|
+---+-----+----------+
```

Is there a way to do this programatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to do it is to use aggregate functions. Sparks comes with a number of predefined ones (average, sum, count, first, collect list, collect set, min, max, ...), so you can always, on your example, do it like this :

```
df.groupBy("id").agg(
    count("id").as("countOfIds"), 
    sum("id").as("sumOfIds"), 
    avg("id").as("avgOfIds")
).show
+---+----------+--------+--------+
| id|countOfIds|sumOfIds|avgOfIds|
+---+----------+--------+--------+
|  1|         3|       3|     1.0|
|  3|         3|       9|     3.0|
|  2|         2|       4|     2.0|
+---+----------+--------+--------+
```

You can view the defined functions inside the [sql.function package documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html), by looking the ones defined as "Aggregate functions". All of those have a SQL syntax equivalent if you are using the SQL oriented syntax.